# Span and pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

The span function is defined below. I am curious as to how **(ys, zs)** is pattern matched with **(x:ys, zs)** where there is already an 'x' and a cons. I some how believed pattern matching would be an in-place replacement, but this blows my mind and had my jaw dropped. This is really beautiful.

I am curious as to if this construct and more is explained in any book (I am currently reading Real World Haskell Chapter 4 and wonder if this book or any other explains this in detail). Sorry if I come off as naive, but to me, this is a fine pattern matching construct and I would love to know more.

```
span p []            = ([],[])
span p xs@(x:xs') 
            | p x       =  (x:ys,zs)
            | otherwise =  ([],xs)
                           where (ys,zs) = span p xs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're right, this *is* beautiful. It is the closest thing to Prolog's [TRMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons), in Haskell.

Let me explain. That definition is equivalent to

```
span p xs = case xs of 
             (x:t) | p x -> let (ys,zs) = span p t in
                            (x:ys,zs)   -- value1
             _           -> ([],xs)     -- value2 constructed from known parts
```

Because Haskell is *lazy*, `value1` is constructed and returned immediately, without any intermediate recursive calls, just as the simple `value2`. At this point `x` is already known (it was bound as part of pattern matching) but `ys` and `zs` are not calculated yet — just their definition is retained alongside the `value1` with two "holes" in it, `(x:_,_)`. Only if either of the "holes" values will be demanded later, their values will be calculated by making the further call to `span` and filling those holes with the destructured result (`let` bindings are pattern matches too).

This is known as guarded recursion in Haskell - the recursive call is guarded against by the constructor(s) - here, `(,)` and `(:)` - creating value with hole(s), to be filled later as needed.

Incidentally, in Prolog this is written as

```
span(P,[], [],[]).       % -- two "inputs", two "outputs"
span(P,XS, A,B):- 
  XS = [X|T],
  ( call(P,X) ->         % -- predicate P holds for X:
      A=[X|YS], B=ZS,    % --   first, the value with holes is created
      span(P,T, YS,ZS)   % --   then, the holes are filled
    ;                    % -- else:
      A=[], B=XS ).      % --   output values are set
```

Answer (score 1):

Much of pattern syntax can also be used for expressions, so that you can use the *same* syntax for taking apart data with a pattern as you use for building it with an expression.

Note that since Haskell values are immutable, there *are* no in place replacements.
The part `(x:ys,zs)` is not itself a pattern, but is an expression that builds a *new* value from the values `x`, `ys` and `zs`, which themselves come from patterns.

`x` comes from the pattern `xs@(x:xs')` and is bound to the first element of the list passed as the second argument of `span`. This also binds `xs'` to the *remainder* of the list, and `xs` to the original whole. (The `@` means "match the pattern to the right but *also* give a name bound to the whole, and is an exception to the rule that patterns can also be used as expressions.)

`ys` and `zs` come from the pattern `(ys,zs)` in `where (ys,zs) = span p xs'`. They are bound to the first and second element of the tuple returned from a *recursive* call of `span p xs'` with the remainder of the list after `x` has been removed.

Putting this together, the expression `(x:ys,zs)` makes a tuple that is the same as the one returned from the recursive `span p xs'`, except that `x` has been consed to the first tuple element.

Someone else will have to answer about books, I learned Haskell too long ago to have read them. But if everything else fails, you can read the [precise definitions in the Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17).